# bulk modify bind9 records (webmin)

Tags: bind, debian-lenny

I have a debian lenny server using webmin to manager bind 9 dns server.

I need to change the A records for 50 domains.

Is there a way to do in bulk mode without modify each domain ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

John underestimates Webmin.

Browse to the BIND DNS module in Webmin

Select the zones you want to update in the "Existing DNS Zones" (check the boxes beside them)

Click "Update Records in Selected"

On the resulting form, set the following:

Record type to update: Address (this is the default)

Current value to change: *address you want to alter*

New value: *new IP address*

Click "Change Records"

You may also need to click the Apply changes link in the top right corner of the BIND module home page in order to reload the BIND zone files after making the change.

Additional documentation for the BIND module in Webmin can be found here: http://doxfer.com/Webmin/BINDDNSServer

Comment: You may be right about me underestimating Webmin. Because I hate it with a passion I've never fully checked out all it's options.

Comment: Now, what did Webmin ever do to you, to cause such animosity?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible using a simplistic interface such as Webmin provides. Easily enough done at the command line though. Using whatever tools you're comfortable with do a search and replace.

Comment: I know that I can use "sed" but I don't know how to change the serial numbers with this tool

Comment: @roberto, I've never used sed, so can't help you with that. FWIW, faced with a similar situation I copy the files or directory to my Windows machine (Linux is not my first language) and use the tools I'm comfortable with. Alternatively, if this is something that's going to be repeated, I'll write something in Perl and copy run that on the target machine. For the serial numbers you can either simply increment them or use the current date/time stamp.